# addLast - doubly circular linkedlist - NullPointerException

Tags: java, linked-list, insert, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

How do you insert an item at the end of a doubly circular linked list? Why do I have a `NullPointerException` when I run this?

```java
   public void addLast( String title, double length ){

    if( isEmpty()){
        head = new Episode(title, length, head, head);
      }else{
      Episode last = head.prev;
      Episode new_episode = new Episode(title, length, head, last);

      }
      }
```

Comment: Could you please rest of your code? The problem is, `head` object is created in only one condition of the if-block. Can't see if it's being set somewhere else

Comment: head is created in the construtor

Answer (score 0):

The code sets the new node's references, but doesn't update the existing references in the list. Fixed noted in commments:

```
    if( isEmpty()){            // assuming if empty, head == null
        head = new Episode(title, length, head, head);
        head.next = head;      // fix
        head.prev = head;      // fix
    } else {
      Episode last = head.prev;
      Episode new_episode = new Episode(title, length, head, last);
      last.next = new_episode; // fix
      head.prev = new_episode; // fix
    }
```